# EJB2 in Eclipse 3.7

Tags: eclipse, ejb, ejb-2.x

I want to create Ejb2 application in my eclipse 3.7 (using jboss 5.0), but evrywhere on internet I am getting only "eclipse 3.7 + Ejb3" examples, are ejb2 not supported on eclise 3.7 ? If it is supported how should I make one ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not want this to be supported by modern tools. Avoid EJB2 (use EJB3 instead).

If you really *have* to use EJB2, then just use the ancient tools from that era and hopefully this will be an extra reason to upgrade as soon as possible.